# Updating profile picture in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here, i upload a new picture to firebase storage, then i retrieve it with getDownloadUrl, and then i update the user profile photoURL, but for some reason it's not working.

```
const imgPath = ref(storage, "images/");
  const imgUpload = () => {
    if (uImg == null) return;

    const imgRef = ref(storage, `images/${uImg.name + v4()}`);
    uploadBytes(imgRef, uImg).then(() => {
      listAll(imgPath).then((response) => {
        response.items.forEach((item) => {
          getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
            setImgUrl([url]);

            updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
              photoURL: `${imgUrl[0]}`,
            })
              .then(() => {
                setProfileImg(auth.currentUser.photoURL);
                console.log("success");
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

`uImg` is the uploaded img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely the current user is updated by the time the updateProfile then statement runs.

Instead update the useState hook as with the imgUrl[0].

```
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { photoURL: `${imgUrl[0]}` })
     .then(() => {
        setProfileImg(imgUrl[0]);
        console.log("success");
 }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

If you want to verify that the profile image was updated print of the value:

```
const auth = getAuth();
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Profile:", auth.currentUser?.photoURL);
}, []);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! But i have other problem, when the page loads, i'm getting the data as `useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUserName(user.displayName);
        setProfileImg(user.photoURL);
      } else {
      }
    });
  }, []);` 
But for some reason the img is not loading, and my img src is `<img src={`${profileImg}`}></img> `

Comment: Missing onAuthStateChanged: useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      setUserName(user.displayName);
      setProfileImg(user.photoURL);
    } else {
    }
  });
}, [onAuthStateChanged]);

Comment: So, i'm actually really lost, because i'm getting every image from the storage and updating the profile picture with the created array element, and the images in the storage are not ordered by the last added, so it's a bit messy. Is there a more efficient way to that? I mean, i'm just trying to put a function to change profile picture, the user uploads an image and it becomes the profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

According to firebase moduler v9 you can update user's basic profile information, the user's display name and profile photo URL with the updateProfile method.

For example:

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: "Jane Q. User", photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Profile updated!
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```